# randomize buttons on in as3 from array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm pretty novice to flash 5.5, im trying to build a quiz for my elementary students.
So far I have made the layout, created the image buttons, and I used to as3 to advance the quiz.

So what I'm, looking for is the ability to shuffle the image buttons/answers. Here is a sample of what i have so far.

```
                          the red ______

apple (button of apple)       boy (button of boy)     pineapple (button with pineapple)
```

In my example, the pictures are buttons, the correct answer is apple. I have tried to create an array, after hours of google searches. This is my code, I'm doing something wrong but I have no idea what. Please help.

Please help.

```
function Main() {

var button:Array = [];
button.push("choice1");
button.push("choice2");
button.push("choice3");
ShuffleArray(button); 
trace(button);

}
function ShuffleArray(button:Array)
{

for (var i:int = button.length-1; i >=0; i--)
{

var randomIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
var itemAtIndex:Object = button[randomIndex]; 
button[randomIndex] = button[i];
button[i] = itemAtIndex;
```

thanks in advance.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this:

```
protected var button:Array=[choice1, choice2, choice3];//note no quotes, puts in the actual objects
function Main() {
   super();
   randomArray=shuffleArray(button);
   var prevX:int = 0;
   var space:int = 10;
   //places the buttons from left to right in the order
   //they were in the random array
   //uses existing y
   for (var i:int=0; i<randomArray.length; i++) {
      var btn:DisplayObject = randomArray[i] as DisplayObject;
      btn.x = prevX;
      prevX = btn.x + btn.width + space;
   }
}

protected function shuffleArray(inArray:Array):Array {
   //create copy of array so as not to alter it
   var tempArray = new Array().concat(inArray);
   //resultarray (we'll be destroying the temp array)
   var resultArray:Array = [];
   while(tempArray.length>0) {
      var index:int = int(Math.random() * tempArray.length);
      //delete object from random location and put it into result array
      resultArray.push(tempArray.splice(index, 1)[0]);
   }
   return resultArray;
}
```

Note this assumes you're using a document Class and that your buttons are already on the stage at the same y position.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. i really appreciate the comments its helping me learn, however, I have no idea what a document class is.  i did a google search to find out and setup a doc class inserted your script with no modification and unfortunately the buttons stayed in the same place.

Comment: Are your buttons named choice1, choice2, choice3? Are you getting any compile errors? The above code was made off the top of my head, so it's never been compiled--a typo could cause it not to run. Also, is your document Class called Main? Having the constructor called Main() will only work if the Class is also called Main.

Comment: yes my buttons are named choice1-3 and are on the stage. I read online how to create a doc class called main i also added it to the flash properties of the original flash. there were no error codes in the compiler. The buttons however didn't shuffle around.

Comment: this is code i tried to use after reading a few more google posts. This also gives me no errors but same result

'function Main() {

var button:Array = [];
button.push("choice1");
button.push("choice2");
button.push("choice3");
shuffle(button); 
for(var i:int=0;i<button.length;i++){

button[i].x = 50+button[i].width*i;

}




}

function shuffle(a:Array) {

    var p:int;

    var t:*;

    var ivar:int;

    for (ivar = a.length-1; ivar>=0; ivar--) {

        p=Math.floor((ivar+1)*Math.random());

        t = a[ivar];

        a[ivar] = a[p];

        a[p] = t;

    }

}'

Comment: I'm thinking you didn't understand my comment about how pushing strings into the array isn't going to help. Just out of curiosity, why did you suddenly decide Flash was the tool for you? Maybe you can start with one of these tools http://www.squidoo.com/gamemaking

Comment: Your correct I didn't understand the comment, I decided to use flash because I used captivate to create a quiz that has only words no pictures. Captivate doesnt allow buttons with pictures, so I was told flash could do the custom buttons and add actions. The most difficult part so far is randomizing location the picture buttons on stage when the frame loads.

Comment: You can use custom buttons in Captivate.  I turned up this in a one-minute web search http://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2008/03/adobe-captivate.html . The Captivate community is better geared toward nontechnical people trying to do technical things, and they'll bear with you when you fail to come back with requested information and constantly switch tack rather than following through with a suggested method until you can make it successful. You can find them here http://forums.adobe.com/community/adobe_captivate

Comment: Amy thank you for all your help, i was able to use buttons in captivate however I cannot shuffle these buttons.  So I'm back to square 1. I'm going to do more research hopefully i can put together something with more flash scripting knowledge